# Wondering how to generate multiple ListGroup.Item in a react component

Tags: reactjs

I was wondering how I can generate multiple list items in my react component. The only thing that varies in this component is the name and value attributes. I know I should probably set those values to props but I'm not sure how to have just one ListGroup.Item but render all of the list items I need. Any help is greatly appreciated! Thanks!

```
export default function ModalButton({ genre }) {
    const [show, setShow] = useState(false);
    const [button, setButton] = useState("Choose...")

    const handleClose = () => setShow(false);
    const handleShow = () => setShow(true);

    const changeButton = e => setButton(e)

    return (
        <>
            <h5 className="inputFont text-center">Genre</h5>
            <Button style={{ backgroundColor: "black", opacity: "1", color: "white", borderColor: "red" }} variant="primary" className="w-100 mb-4 inputFont" onClick={handleShow}>
                {button}
            </Button>
            <Modal show={show} onHide={handleClose}>
                <Modal.Header closeButton className="modal-bg inputFont">
                    Pick A Genre
                </Modal.Header>
                <Modal.Body className="modal-bg">
                    <ListGroup >
                        <ListGroup.Item className="modal-bg"><Button style={{ backgroundColor: "black", opacity: ".8", color: "white", borderColor: "red" }} className="inputFont w-100" name="Action And Adventure" value="10673,10702,11804,11828,1192487,1365,1568,2125,2653,43040,43048,4344,46576,7442,75418,76501,77232,788212,801362,899,9584" onClick={e => { genre(e.target.value); changeButton(e.target.name); handleClose() }}>Action and Adventure</Button></ListGroup.Item>
                        <ListGroup.Item className="modal-bg"><Button style={{ backgroundColor: "black", opacity: ".8", color: "white", borderColor: "red" }} className="inputFont w-100" name="Musicals" value="13335,13573,32392,52852,55774,59433,84488,88635" onClick={e => { genre(e.target.value); changeButton(e.target.name); handleClose() }}>Musicals</Button></ListGroup.Item>
                        <ListGroup.Item className="modal-bg"><Button style={{ backgroundColor: "black", opacity: ".8", color: "white", borderColor: "red" }} className="inputFont w-100" name="Sci-Fi" value="1492,108533,11014,1372,1568,1694,2595,2729,3327,3916,47147,4734,49110,50232,52780,52849,5903,6000,6926,852491" onClick={e => { genre(e.target.value); changeButton(e.target.name); handleClose() }}>Sci-Fi</Button></ListGroup.Item>
                        <ListGroup.Item className="modal-bg"><Button style={{ backgroundColor: "black", opacity: ".8", color: "white", borderColor: "red" }} className="inputFont w-100" name="Fantasy" value="9744" onClick={e => { genre(e.target.value); changeButton(e.target.name); handleClose() }}>Fantasy</Button></ListGroup.Item>
                        <ListGroup.Item className="modal-bg"><Button style={{ backgroundColor: "black", opacity: ".8", color: "white", borderColor: "red" }} className="inputFont w-100" name="Thrillers" value="10306,10499,10504,10719,11014,11140,1138506,1321,1774,3269,43048,46588,5505,58798,65558,6867,75390,78507,799,852488,8933,98911,9147,972" onClick={e => { genre(e.target.value); changeButton(e.target.name); handleClose() }}>Thrillers</Button></ListGroup.Item>
                        <ListGroup.Item className="modal-bg"><Button style={{ backgroundColor: "black", opacity: ".8", color: "white", borderColor: "red" }} className="inputFont w-100" name="Anime" value="10695,11146,2653,2729,3063,413820,452,6721,9302,7424" onClick={e => { genre(e.target.value); changeButton(e.target.name); handleClose() }}>Anime</Button></ListGroup.Item>
                        <ListGroup.Item className="modal-bg"><Button style={{ backgroundColor: "black", opacity: ".8", color: "white", borderColor: "red" }} className="inputFont w-100" name="Children and Family" value="10056,27480,27950,28034,28083,28233,48586,5455,561,6218,6796,6962,78120,89513,783" onClick={e => { genre(e.target.value); changeButton(e.target.name); handleClose() }}>Children and Family</Button></ListGroup.Item>
                        <ListGroup.Item className="modal-bg"><Button style={{ backgroundColor: "black", opacity: ".8", color: "white", borderColor: "red" }} className="inputFont w-100" name="Comedies" value="1009,10256,10375,105,10778,11559,11755,1208951,1333288,1402,1747,17648,2030,2700,31694,3300,34157,3519,3996,4058,4195,43040,4426,4906,52104,52140,52847,5286,5475,5610,56174,58905,59169,61132,61330,6197,63092,63115,6548,711366,7120,72407,7539,77599,77907,78163,78655,79871,7992,852492,869,89585,9302,9434,9702,9736" onClick={e => { genre(e.target.value); changeButton(e.target.name); handleClose() }}>Comedies</Button></ListGroup.Item>
                        <ListGroup.Item className="modal-bg"><Button style={{ backgroundColor: "black", opacity: ".8", color: "white", borderColor: "red" }} className="inputFont w-100" name="Documentaries" value="10005,10105,10599,1159,15456,180,2595,2616,2760,28269,3652,3675,4006,4720,48768,49110,49547,50232,5161,5349,55087,56178,58710,60026,6839,7018,72384,77245,852494,90361,9875" onClick={e => { genre(e.target.value); changeButton(e.target.name); handleClose() }}>Documentaries</Button></ListGroup.Item>
                        <ListGroup.Item className="modal-bg"><Button style={{ backgroundColor: "black", opacity: ".8", color: "white", borderColor: "red" }} className="inputFont w-100" name="Dramas" value="11,11075,11714,1208954,1255,12995,13158,2150,25955,26009,2696,2748,2757,2893,29809,3179,31901,34204,3653,3682,384,3916,3947,4282,4425,452,4961,500,5012,52148,52904,56169,58755,58796,59064,6206,62235,6616,6763,68699,6889,711367,71591,71591,72354,7243,7539,75459,76507,78628,852493,89804,9299,9847,9873,5763" onClick={e => { genre(e.target.value); changeButton(e.target.name); handleClose() }}>Dramas</Button></ListGroup.Item>
                        <ListGroup.Item className="modal-bg"><Button style={{ backgroundColor: "black", opacity: ".8", color: "white", borderColor: "red" }} className="inputFont w-100" name="Sports" value="180,25788,4370,5286,7243,9327" onClick={e => { genre(e.target.value); changeButton(e.target.name); handleClose() }}>Sports</Button></ListGroup.Item>
                        <ListGroup.Item className="modal-bg"><Button style={{ backgroundColor: "black", opacity: ".8", color: "white", borderColor: "red" }} className="inputFont w-100" name="Horror" value="10695,10944,1694,42023,45028,48303,61546,75405,75804,75930,8195,83059,8711,89585" onClick={e => { genre(e.target.value); changeButton(e.target.name); handleClose() }}>Horror</Button></ListGroup.Item>
                        <ListGroup.Item className="modal-bg"><Button style={{ backgroundColor: "black", opacity: ".8", color: "white", borderColor: "red" }} className="inputFont w-100" name="Romance" value="29281,36103,502675" onClick={e => { genre(e.target.value); changeButton(e.target.name); handleClose() }}>Romance</Button></ListGroup.Item>
                        <ListGroup.Item className="modal-bg"><Button style={{ backgroundColor: "black", opacity: ".8", color: "white", borderColor: "red" }} className="inputFont w-100" name="Classics" value="10032,11093,13158,29809,2994,31273,31574,31694,32392,46553,46560,46576,46588,47147,47465,48303,48586,48744,76186" onClick={e => { genre(e.target.value); changeButton(e.target.name); handleClose() }}>Classics</Button></ListGroup.Item>
                    </ListGroup>
                </Modal.Body>
            </Modal>
        </>
```

Comment: I don't quite understand the question. Are the **name** and **value** coming from a different source (like, a database) or are they static data.
If they are static, create an array of objects ( like: `[{name: "...", value: "..."}, ...]` and map them to `ListGroup.Item`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to create an array for the `listGroupItems` and then loop through them like this:

```
export default function ModalButton({ genre }) {
  const [show, setShow] = useState(false);
  const [button, setButton] = useState("Choose...");

  const handleClose = () => setShow(false);
  const handleShow = () => setShow(true);

  const listGroupArray = [
    {
      name: "something",
      value: "somethingElse",
    },
    {
      name: "secondSomething",
      value: "secondSomethingElse",
    },
  ];

  const changeButton = (e) => setButton(e);

  return (
    <>
      <h5 className="inputFont text-center">Genre</h5>
      <Button
        style={{
          backgroundColor: "black",
          opacity: "1",
          color: "white",
          borderColor: "red",
        }}
        variant="primary"
        className="w-100 mb-4 inputFont"
        onClick={handleShow}
      >
        {button}
      </Button>
      <Modal show={show} onHide={handleClose}>
        <Modal.Header closeButton className="modal-bg inputFont">
          Pick A Genre
        </Modal.Header>
        <Modal.Body className="modal-bg">
          <ListGroup>
            {listGroupArray.map((item) => (
              <ListGroup.Item className="modal-bg">
                <Button
                  style={{
                    backgroundColor: "black",
                    opacity: ".8",
                    color: "white",
                    borderColor: "red",
                  }}
                  className="inputFont w-100"
                  name={item.name}
                  value={item.value}
                  onClick={(e) => {
                    genre(item.value);
                    changeButton(item.name);
                    handleClose();
                  }}
                >
                  Action and Adventure
                </Button>
              </ListGroup.Item>
            ))}
          </ListGroup>
        </Modal.Body>
      </Modal>
    </>
  );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You will need to have all your `ListGroup.Item` data stored in an array of objects.

Then you need to map over that array and render `ListGroup.Item` with dynamic data.

Something Like Below: `(Note: This is just a Demo, you can use all the data in the object)`

```
const listGroupData = [
    {id:1,
     name="Action And Adventure",value:""10673,10702,11804,11828,1192487,1365,1568,2125,2653,43040,43048,4344,46576,7442,75418,76501,77232,788212,801362,899,9584"},
    {id:2,name="Playand fun Adventure",value:"9744"},
    {id:3,name="Action And Adventure", value:"29281,36103,502675"},
     ...
]
```

Then in your Component :

```
 <ListGroup>
     {
      listGroupData.map(item=>(
          <ListGroup.Item className="modal-bg" key={item.id}><Button style={{ backgroundColor: "black", opacity: ".8", color: "white", borderColor: "red" }} className="inputFont w-100" name="Action And Adventure" value={item.value} onClick={e => { genre(e.target.value); changeButton(e.target.name); handleClose() }}>Action and Adventure</Button></ListGroup.Item>
       )); 
     }
</ListGroup>
```

Answer (score 0):

Create an items array an store name and value to this like below:

```
const items = [{ name: 'Action And Adventure', value: '10673,10702,11804,11828,1192487,1365,1568,2125,2653,43040,43048,4344,46576,7442,75418,76501,77232,788212,801362,899,9584'}, {...}, {...}];
```

Use `map` function to render `<ListGroup.Item>` like below:

```
<ListGroup>
  {items.map(item => (
    <ListGroup.Item className="modal-bg"><Button style={{ backgroundColor: "black", opacity: ".8", color: "white", borderColor: "red" }} className="inputFont w-100" name={item.name} value={item.value} onClick={e => { genre(e.target.value); changeButton(e.target.name); handleClose() }}>Classics</Button></ListGroup.Item>
  ))}
</ListGroup>
```